# Screen video capture including mouse cursor on Mac?

Tags: javascript, macos, google-chrome-extension, electron, screen-capture

I've been scratching my head for the past week and still cannot find a clear answer regarding this issue...

Basically, I'm building a desktop app for screen/desktop/window capturing using Web API's.

Seems that on Mac, mouse cursor does not appear in the stream. Please see https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238434 and 
https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/8278

But somehow, [a Chrome extension exists](https://www.hyfy.io/) and works perfectly fine. 
Can someone please explain how to successfully record screen using Web technologies to avoid ffmpeg and native scripts? How did those guys manage to overcome this issue on Mac? Does this issue actually exist?

Thanks.

Comment: You know the bug you linked to has been marked as a dupe of [this one](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238434) which has been marked as fixed in... 2013 (Not saying it does work, but it certanly did ;-P)

Comment: yeah not sure how that can be fixed if Electron uses same API as Chromium does, both should work, but still, many apps for screen recording keep finding native workarounds for this issue, Eg: Kap, https://github.com/wulkano/aperture.js

Comment: Running into the same issue. Will share my findings if you do the same.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a bug where the cursor is not recorded when external displays are hooked to your device.
In my instance, I've got two monitors hooked to a Macbook Pro.

A workaround is unhooking your displays or setting your displays to mirror.

I haven't been able to test a set up with a Mac Pro or Mini hooked to just one or multiple displays.

I created an issue in the Chromium bug report.

Answer (score 0):

This has been fixed since Chrome 56!